# Can’t Boot From Live DVD

Tags: 17.10

There is something amiss on my hard drive’s boot which I thought I could either fix through the live DVD or even reinstall Ubuntu 17.10 (64 bit) if needed. I do know how to make it boot from the optical drive and it tries, then continues onto the problematic hard drive. Even completely disabling the hard drive as a boot device in the BIOS fails with a DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER. Pressing Enter starts the problem all over again. The live disk itself is just fine and boots on other PCs but not on this one so any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to look into another bootable cd/dvd and see if you can get that to boot... have you been able to boot to the CD/DVD in the past? if you haven't ever tried, it may be bios/uefi related maybe but if it has worked in the past and you try another bootable cd/dvd  that works on other machines and it wont work its probably hardware related ... If it can boot to a USB .. I would try a bootable USB

Comment: On some of my machines (older legacy boot hardware) I just hit <f9> (or other key as appropriate for brand) and a blue menu pops up asking me what device to boot. On some machines I make changes in BIOS to enable other devices (usb-key etc) to boot, as those bioses by default only allow hdd/sdd booting.  Check your bios, for boot-order or boot option.  (note: you have to be quick to use fn keys)

Comment: I have booted to it many times but I am begining to suspect a hardware issue as you implied as I just discovered it does boot to a USB DVD drive. Thank you for the suggestion! Edit: One thing I noticed after posting is that both the hard drive and the optical drive are showing as slaves in the BIOS when there is no way to connect the cables wrong and no jumpers that I can find so I’ll have to do more research.